# how to convert map into set

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

i got some issues trying to convert my map into a set
I got a "Chanson" object with this member data :

```
std::map<std::string,Artiste*> m_interpretes;
```

Here is how i add my `*Artiste` to my map :

```
void Chanson::addArtiste(Artiste* a) throw (ExceptionArtiste, ExceptionLangueIncompatible)
{
    if(a!=NULL)
    {
        if(a->getLangue() == this->getLangue())
        {
            m_interpretes.insert(pair<string, Artiste*>(a->getNom(), a));
            //m_interpretes[a->getNom()] = a;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ExceptionLangueIncompatible(a,this);
        }
    }
}




set<Artiste*> Chanson::getArtistes() const
{
    //set<Artiste*> machin;
    return set<Artiste*> (m_interpretes.begin(), m_interpretes.end());
}
```

i got this error due to this function :

> Error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::set<_Kty>::insert(Artiste *&&) : impossible de convertir le paramètre 1 de const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> en 'Artiste *&&'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\set  179 1

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: why are you storing pointers in a container? this seems like a memory leak waiting to happen.

Comment: Second question: Why are you using dynamic exception specifications? They cause all sorts of strange things to happen and slow down your code, general advice at the moment is to avoid them completely.

Comment: In fact, in the latest standard, dynamic exception specifications are deprecated.

Comment: @user2079303: Actually, they were deprecated in the _previous_ standard!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, they still *remain* deprecated, unless I've missed something.

Comment: @user2079303: Absolutely. I'm just emphasising that this deprecation is not a new idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::set` constructor you are trying to use will try to construct an element from everything the range you pass it:

```
return set<Artiste*> (m_interpretes.begin(), m_interpretes.end());
```

But the element type of that range is

```
std::pair<const std::string, Artiste*>
```

which is definitely not convertible to `Artiste*`, which is why you are getting that error about not being able to convert. You could just do it manually though:

```
std::set<Artiste*> s;
for (const auto& pair : m_interpretes) {
    s.insert(pair.second);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A map is an associative data structure, while a set only contains unordered collection of items, so adding a pair (key, value) is invalid for the latter and only holds for the former.

To make a `set` of keys from a `map`, you can do

```
std::set<Artiste*> tempSet;
std::transform(m_interpretes.cbegin(), m_interpretes.cend(),
               std::inserter(tempSet, tempSet.begin()),
               [](const std::pair<std::string, Artiste*>& key_value)
               { return key_value.second; });
return tempSet;
```

Comment: I feel like having problems with that : return set<Artiste*> (m_interpretes.begin(), m_interpretes.end()); , seems like i can add objects to by map without any troubles

Comment: The error string seems to relate to the call to `insert`.

Comment: m_interpretes.insert(a) is incorrect aswell till my map object declaration is std::map<std::string,Artiste*> m_interpretes;

Comment: But you error says that you've changed it to a `std::set` isn't it? `std::set<_Kty>::insert(Artiste *&&) `.

Comment: nah, i just want my function "set<Artiste*> Chanson::getArtistes() const{}" to return a set instead of a map.

Comment: @Nico I see, I perhaps didn't read the question properly, I've fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
return set<Artiste*> (m_interpretes.begin(), m_interpretes.end());
```

If you have a look at the types you get from the [map::begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/) and [map::end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/) functions you see that you get an iterator of `std::pair<string, Artiste*>`.

The problem is that the [set::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) function expects the iterators it is given to be of type `Artiste*`.

The simplest fix would be to create the set with a for loop, as shown in Barry's answer.