# Fastest way to find two unrelated objects in many-to-many relationship and implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, many-to-many, relationship

The basic setting is that, suppose we have two simple classes:

```
class User {
     private:
        int id;
     public:
        User(int id){ this->id = id };
};

class Channel {
     private:
        std::string name;
     public:
        Channel(std::string name) { this->name = name };
};
```

These two classes are supposed to be in Many-to-Many relationship with each other, e.g. each `User` can join many `Channel`s and each `Channel` can have many `User`s.

Number of `Channel` objects - few hundreds. Number of `User` objects - tens of thousands.

**Task formulation:** Given a particular `Channel` object, I must find a `User` which is **unrelated** to it, as fast as possible.

**Question:**

1) What would be the optimal realisation of such a many-to-many relationship, considering the given task? Is there any specific algorithm for such a problem (other than straightforward iteration through all relations)?

2) How to implement this, if relations are supposed to have some additional properties, e.g. store the time when `User` joined `Channel`?

*My thoughts:* The first idea was create some additional class like

```
class UserChannelRel {
    private:
        User* userPtr;
        Channel* chPtr;
        float timeJoined;
    public:
        UserChannelRel(User* user, Channel* channel, float tm) {
             this->userPtr = user;
             this->chPtr = channel;
             this->timeJoined = tm;
        }
};
```

And store those in some big standard container (vector?). But then iterating through all the elements seems pretty slow.

Comment: CPU vs memory space, the never ending question ^^

Comment: "must find a User which is unrelated": how to choose out of all the unrelated users? Randomly?

Comment: @geza
Yes, which user - does not matter. Just need the first suitable one.

Comment: If a channel has less than half of the users, then you can do this easily with a bit-matrix: each bit stores whether the user and the channel is related. Then choose a random user, check it's bit. If related, then choose another. Keep choosing until an unrelated is found. O(1) amortized time. Or, you can store a list in each Channel, which stores all unrelated users. Here, worst case is O(1), but needs more memory.

Comment: @geza
Thanks for the idea! Though, in my task, Channel can have almost all users, or even all of them (tens of thousands), so I still have to find from those remaining users, or return that there are no unrelated users left, as fast as I can.
Would bit-matrix be suitable for it also?

Comment: Given sorted vectors (or whatever) of all users, and all users on a channel, finding the the first difference in the two vectors is trivial.

Comment: @Shawn
Well, this would be O(n) in the worst case (when vectors are the same), and worst cases can happen quite often in my situation + huge number of users, but anyway thanks for the idea.

Comment: @SergeyDylda Adding a check for that special case is also trivial if it's actually an issue. Just see if the vectors are the same size.

Comment: @Shawn
Could you please elaborate a little bit on the check (maybe post an answer)? E.g. I have 20k users and Channel has 19.999 of then entered already, except for 1 random user. He can be anywhere inside those 20k, so I'll have to go over all of them anyway (in the worst case).

Comment: @SergeyDylda: is the `id` in `User` small (I mean, is it in the range of number-of-users)? So can it be used as an index in a matrix?

Comment: @geza Well, In my situation `id` really is a phone number. But it is not a problem to rewrite `id` to be primary small index ( < number-of-users), so yes.

Comment: @SergeyDylda: you can use my second idea then: each channel has a list of unrelated users. The list should be stored in an array. When a user joins, it is removed from the list (this can be done O(1), as the id is the index). When a user leaves, it is added to the list. You can use the head of the list as a "random" unrelated user (each list node is just a prev+next pointer). This is fast on paper, the only problem is it takes much memory: 100k users, 1k channel:  ~1.5GB memory on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @SergeyDylda: but of course, it can be optimized, using 16-bit ints instead of 64-bit pointers, so it is ~400MB.

Comment: The answer to this depends on two bits of information, neither of which you have specified.   How do you keep track of all `User` and `Channel` objects that have been created?    How do you keep track of the relationship between those objects?     If your answer to any of those questions is "I don't", then there is no point to your question.

Comment: @geza
Thank you! Idea with lists of unrealated users seems good, I'll try it!

Comment: @Peter
`User` objects are loaded upon start from database into a container (i.e. `set`). The set of users do not change during the runtime. `Channel` objects are also loaded from database into a container, but the set of Channels can vary by external means (application can receive commands to add/remove channels from another script by socket). When I receive a certain request through the socket, I need to take a channel name from the request, find a user who didn't join it yet, create a new relation somehow and respond with some serialized data from user object back through the socket.

Comment: @Peter 
The problem is how to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you can create two repositories to hold the full list of users on one side and the full list of channels on the other.  Typically, you'd do this with [maps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
map<int, User> users;
map<std::string, Channel> channels;
```

Then, I'd propose to have for each channel a [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of users:

```
class Channel {
     private:
        std::string name;
        std::set<int> subscribers; 
     public:
        Channel(std::string name):name(name) { };
        void add(int userid) {
            subscribers.insert(userid);
        }
};
```

Then to find users not related to a channel,  you could iterate through the users and easily check if included in the channel.

Alternatively,  you could also use a global set of users (either maintaining set membership in same time than the repository,  or by [creating the set from the map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26425470/3723423)) and use [`set_difference()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) to generate the set of users who are not subscribers.

[Example of use](https://ideone.com/C4rCUb) of `set_difference`:

```
set<int> a { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};   // imagine a set of all the users
set<int> b{ 2,3,8};            // imagine a set of the subscribers of a channel
vector<int> c;                 // container with the users who are not subscribers

set_difference(a.begin(),a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), back_inserter(c)); 
copy(c.begin(), c.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout," "));
```

How to chose between the two approaches ? The first approach, iterating and checking, has the advantage to quickly find first users and start doing something with the proposal.  The iteration can ba optimized, by making use of the fact that sets and maps are sorted. You don't need to find all the users.  The second approach is elegant, but with large user base, it could take more time since you need to have the full result before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using `std::shared_ptr`?

Each `User` would have a set of `shared_ptr` to the `Channels` they join which saves memory since one `Channel` can be joined by multiple Users.

You can do the same to store the `Users` in your `Channels`.

And then, you can have your `Users` in a `vector` and use a sort (an efficient one like merge maybe, try benchmarking the existing sorts that are out there) that looks if the `User` has a pointer the `Channel` you're looking at.

Comment: Thought about this. But what's the sort here for?

Comment: You could sort the array of users so that the ones unrelated to the channel you're looking at end up at the end (or the beginning, that's on you) of the array. That is, if I understood well what you're trying to do !

Comment: I do not need all the users which are unrelated. I need just the first one suitable as fast as possible.

Comment: Then I suggest @geza solution ;)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is tricky because you have bidirectional relationships which will cause circular dependencies. It is also quite slow for some operations.

Comment: right, haven't thought of this... So I checked about circular dependencies and I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50665301/circular-dependency-with-the-relationships-contains-and-is-in , I feel like it could be useful in this case, even tho the problem seems to have found a solution.